# Unnecessary code generating in HTML website

Tags: html, css

I developed HTML website. Used HTML and CSS only.

While looking into view source, it is showing unnecessary code at the end of the page and files too.

How can i solve this?

[image]

Comment: You did not write this code? Could be a from a plugin you installed in the browser...

Comment: Yes, i didn't write that code, it is generating automatically.

Comment: Can you check the source in different browsers?

Comment: Yes, checked in chrome too. Getting same error script in different browsers.

Comment: plz share you codes in fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're infected with Ramnit file infector virus. It's not curable.

> Win32/Ramnit.A is a file infector with IRCBot functionality which
>   infects .exe, and .HTML/HTM files, and opens a back door that
>   compromises your computer. Using this backdoor, a remote attacker can
>   access and instruct the infected computer to download and execute more
>   malicious files. The infected .HTML or .HTM files may be detected as
>   Virus:VBS/Ramnit.A. Win32/Ramnit.A!dll is a related file infector
>   often seen with this infection. It too has IRCBot functionality which
>   infects .exe, .dll and .HTML/HTM files and opens a back door that
>   compromises your computer. This component is injected into the default
>   web browser by Worm:Win32/Ramnit.A which is dropped by a Ramnit
>   infected executable file.

**Source: http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/not-curable-win32-ramnit-a-infected-and-ruined-everything-please-help.195427/**

You'll probably need to wipe the hard disk and reinstall OS

Comment: How have you concluded that the file is infected with this particular virus? The link you've provided does not appear to show any code which matches the code injected into the OP's file. A suggestion to format and re-install the OS is a drastic one and should be made with supporting evidence - what can you provide that adds weight to your interpretation, conclusion and suggestion?

Comment: How do you know it's Ramnit?

Comment: Ok apparently this virus has many variations, some of which are not curable, depending on the computer security, additional sources: [1](http://www.lavasoft.com/mylavasoft/malware-descriptions/blog/viruswin32ramnita), [2](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1168942?tstart=0), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840532/remove-vbscript-or-deactivate-vbscript-from-html-source-code),